# Python - Matplotlib FuncAnimation - Mac - Not returning points

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the following code I am attempting to have points iteratively added to a graph.  Since I am on OSX, I am not using blit=True.  I can get a single point at the original to plot and can see output from my update function (fed from a generator).  I can also see that my coordinates are being appended to the array of coordinates to be plotted.  What am I missing in getting my generated / updated points visualized?

the stromboli function, called by data_gen() returns a pair of coordinates.  It could be a random x,y for all intents and purposes.

```
#Visualization Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update(coord):
    print coord[0], coord[1]
    pt.set_xdata(numpy.append(pt.get_xdata(),coord[0]))
    pt.set_ydata(numpy.append(pt.get_ydata(),coord[1]))
    print pt.get_xdata()
    return pt,

def data_gen():
   while True:
        yield stromboli(args.velocity)

#Visualization
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
pt, = ax.plot([], [],'ro')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100)

plt.plot(0,0,'b*')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be getting something funny with effective closures (are you running this in an interactive environment?) in that `pt` will be defined from a previous code execution, which is what gets grabbed when `def update` runs.  You then make a new version of `pt` and but that is not what is getting updated by `update`

Either move `pt, = ax.plot([],[],'ro')` *above* the definition of `update` or try passing in `pt` as an argument.

ex:

```
def update(coord,pt):
    print coord[0], coord[1]
    pt.set_xdata(numpy.append(pt.get_xdata(),coord[0]))
    pt.set_ydata(numpy.append(pt.get_ydata(),coord[1]))
    print pt.get_xdata()
    return pt,

....

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, fargs = (pt,),interval=100)
```